# How to create a user input list that stops at X and prints out sum and len

Tags: python

I just started learning python and I'm writing a program which continuously accepts numeric inputs from the user and adds it to a list. However when the user enters an X it should print out how many numbers have been entered and the sum of them all.
I've rewritten the code numerous times, but here's where I'm just stuck at.

```
list = []
number = int(input("Enter numbers: "))
while number != "x" or "X":
    list.append(number)
    break

    print(list)


print("The length of the list is:",len.list)
print("The sum of the list is:",sum(list))
```

I seem to be missing something because it just creates an infinite loop

Comment: You are converting the input to integer and then comparing it to string which fails always and so the loop never terminates.

Comment: Note that `("x" or "X")` always returns `'x'`. What you need there is probably `while number not in {'x', 'X'}` . Also, not that you are not reading new numbers in the while loop! This will run forever since the value of `number` never changes in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your original post, consider the following (with comments)

```
# 1. Don't use `list` since it is a built-in ctor (list())
lst = []

# 2. Loop forever
while True:
    # 3. Ask the user and keep the input as string!
    number_str = input("Enter number: ")

    # 4. Check if we need to bail!
    if number_str in {"x", "X"}:
        break

    # 5. ... and if not append it to the list
    lst.append(int(number_str))

print(lst)


print("The length of the list is:",len(lst))
print("The sum of the list is:",sum(lst))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 ~/tmp/so.py
Enter number: 1
Enter number: 2
Enter number: 3
Enter number: X
[1, 2, 3]
```

Alternatively, if you want the user to input everything at once you can do the following:

```
numbers_str = input("Enter numbers (space-separated): ")
lst = []

for str_num in numbers_str.split(" "):
    if str_num in {'x', 'X'}:
        break
    lst.append(int(str_num))


print(lst)
print("The length of the list is:",len(lst))
print("The sum of the list is:",sum(lst))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 ~/tmp/so2.py
Enter numbers (space-separated): 1 2 3 X 4 5
[1, 2, 3]
The length of the list is: 3
The sum of the list is: 6
```

Note that as in other answers, you will have to handle bad user input!

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors, bad `while` placement, usage of `list` as variable name, absence of validation and error handling, try fixed one ;-)

```
mylist = []
while True:
  try:
    number = input("Enter numbers: ")
    if number.lower() == 'x':
      print("The length of the list is:",len(mylist))
      print("The sum of the list is:",sum(mylist))
      break
    else:
      number = int(number)
      mylist.append(number)
  except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
numbers = []

# Loop forever
while True:

    # Take the input and convert is to lower case
    number = input().lower()

    # If the input is "x", then the code needs to 
    # print the count and sum of the previous numbers.
    # We get out of the loop and do just that.
    if number == "x":
        break

    # If the input is not "x", then we know that it has to be 
    # a number. So, we convert it to "int" and add it to our 
    # numbers list.
    numbers.append(int(number))


print("Total:", len(numbers))
print("Sum:", sum(numbers))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.